# angular download pdf file error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pdf

In my angular app I get pdf byte and show the file using blob

This is my code

```
siteService.downloadPdf().then(function (response) {

    var file = new Blob([response], { type: 'application/pdf' });
    if (window.navigator && window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) {
        window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(file);
    }
    else {
        var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
        window.location.href = fileURL;
    }

});
```

When I try to download the file I got an error that the file does not saved
[image]

This error is when I save the file as is (without the `.pdf`) and also after adding the `.pdf`

[image]